# Change the wrong Disqus color for comment user name

Tags: javascript, html, css, disqus

i have a problem with Disqus integration in plain js.
All text colors are right except for user names:

[image: example image]

The js integration is standard, setting for theme in Disqus admin is "Auto".

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.identifier = '<?php echo str_pad($product_id, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>';
};
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://xxx.disqus.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
```

This is the generated css that Disqus use:

[image: CSS]

Usual css edits not work, also js style updates not work.

Thanks.

Edit: added js declaration code.

Comment: Please insert the relevant HTML and CSS as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without code we cant see anythin and therefore cant help.

Comment: @FabianS. Added, but i used standard code and custom css is not working for disqus frame.